# Read data from updating dat file in Fortran

Tags: text, fortran, read-data

I have an output from a code in dat format. The file has the following format

```
Text
Text
Text
Text
3241234234
234234
23423423
34123424
1324234
iteration pressure temperature density
1 1234 312 2.12
2 1235 321 2.15
3 1234 312 2.12
4 1235 321 2.15
5 1234 312 2.12
6 1235 321 2.15
pressure temperature density
7 1234 312 2.12
8 1235 321 2.15
9 1234 312 2.12
10 1235 321 2.15
11 1234 312 2.12
warning pressure update is not linked
12 1235 321 2.15
pressure temperature density
13 1234 312 2.12
14 1235 321 2.15
15 1234 312 2.12
warning pressure update is not linked
16 1235 321 2.15
17 1234 312 2.12
18 1235 321 2.15
end of iterations
simulation time
end loop
end of code
```

I have written a code in which I open the dat file. Read it as a text using iostat. Then I skip the header text line and random numbers etc up to iteration line. Then read the numbers (iterations pressure temperature density). But I am stuck at few places where I need help.

1. The opening text lines are not constant. Sometimes these are 4 lines and sometimes five or six. Every time I have to adjust the number of lines and compile it again. Is there a way to automate this. I mean the code itself will count the text lines and skip them. Same is the next random numbers.
2. What I want to do is to skip the lines from start to iteration. But these are changing too. Read the numeric data only

   1 1234 312 2.12
   2 1235 321 2.15
   3 1234 312 2.12
   4 1235 321 2.15
   5 1234 312 2.12
   6 1235 321 2.15
   7 1234 312 2.12
   8 1235 321 2.15
   9 1234 312 2.12
   10 1235 321 2.15
   11 1234 312 2.12
   12 1235 321 2.15
   13 1234 312 2.12
   14 1235 321 2.15
   15 1234 312 2.12
   16 1235 321 2.15
   17 1234 312 2.12
   18 1235 321 2.15

and then write this data as the output file.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. If you wrote some code you should always show it. Please use capital letters at the start of each sentence and for the word I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does what you asked for. This code assumes that the data is stored in *input.dat* and will print the output to *output.dat*. The logic is quite simple. First, the lines are read until a line starting with the keyword WORD_OF_INTEREST (here **iteration**) is detected. Then we start reading the remaining lines, assuming that there are 4 fields per line (i.e. iteration, pressure temperature density). Lines that do not obey this pattern are skipped.

The comments will help you understand the algorithm.

```
    program readData

       implicit none

       integer, parameter :: wp = selected_real_kind(15) ! double-precision floats
       integer, parameter :: ip = selected_int_kind(8) ! long integers

       character (len = *), parameter ::               &
          WORD_OF_INTEREST = 'iteration'      

       integer (kind = ip), parameter ::               & 
          LENGTH_WORD = len(WORD_OF_INTEREST),         &! calculate length of the word you are trying to find; that is, "iteration"
          NO_READING_ERROR = 0,                        &
          END_OF_FILE = -1

       integer (kind = ip) ::                          &
          handleFileInput,                             &
          handleFileOutput,                            &
          iteration,                                   &
          idError

       real (kind = wp) ::                             &
          pressure,                                    &
          temperature,                                 &
          density

       character (len = LENGTH_WORD) ::                & 
          line

    ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! Start executable section 
    ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       ! Open the input and output files
       open(newUnit = handleFileInput, file = 'input.dat')
       open(newUnit = handleFileOutput, file = 'output.dat')

       ! Read data file until a line starting with WORD_OF_INTEREST is encountered
       do

          read(handleFileInput, *) line
          if (line == WORD_OF_INTEREST) exit

       end do


       ! Read the rest of the file
       do

          read(handleFileInput, *, iostat = idError) iteration, pressure, temperature, density

          ! Handle different types of errors
          if (idError == NO_READING_ERROR) then

             write(handleFileOutput, *) iteration, pressure, temperature, density

          else if (idError == END_OF_FILE) then

             exit

          else

             continue 

          end if

       end do



       close(handleFileInput)
       close(handleFileOutput)

    end program readData
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Regards